# How to increase font without affecting grid spacing?

Tags: formatting, style, grid-layouts

Here's an example of the problem, say you have a `Grid` with particular spacings that looks like this:

```
disk = Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 10];
opts = {Alignment -> Right, Spacings -> {{0.5, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2}}, .5}};
grid = {If[Mod[#, 4] == 0, ToString@#, ""] & /@ Range[12], Table[disk, 12]};
Grid[grid, BaseStyle -> 10, Sequence @@ opts]
```

[image]

You may want to increase the text size a little, however, this changes the spacing which is not desired:

```
Grid[grid, BaseStyle -> 30, Sequence @@ opts]
```

[image]

I'd like to keep *both the size and spacing of dots the same* (it's ok for text to extend left over multiple dots). This rules out using `ItemSize -> All`:

```
Grid[grid, ItemSize -> All, Dividers -> All, BaseStyle -> 30, Sequence @@ opts]
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure there's an easy trick to doing this. Note: Magnify does not work for me because it won’t preserve my settings when Exported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Since `Spacings` *are in units of current font size*, we need to adjust the vertical spacings when font size is changed.
2. We can modify the first row to make use of `SpanFromLeft` to allow content to extend multiple cells to the left.

```
grid2 = {If[Mod[#, 4] == 3, ToString@(# + 1), 
     If[Mod[#, 4] == 0, SpanFromLeft, ""]] & /@ Range[12], 
  Table[disk, 12]}

Grid[grid2, BaseStyle -> 30, 
 Spacings -> {{0.5 , {0.5, 0.5, .5, 2}}, .5/12}, Alignment -> Right]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
g = Grid[grid, BaseStyle -> 10, Sequence @@ opts]
Magnify[g, 2]
```

Comment: I can’t use magnify